Modify lang system with timer bug
I want to write a program that monitors a process. If the process takes focus, the program should change the keyboard to one selected in a listbox which lists the installed keyboards (lst_box_clavier1). If the monitored process loses focus, the program should change the keyboard towards the one selected in lst_box_clavier2.
To do this I use a timer, whose monitoring interval is defined by the user. The first timer, calling timer_data works as is, it monitors which process has the focus and notes it in the lbl_active_process and the same for the active keyboard. Once the start button is clicked it launches the timer_switch which compares the contents of the active lbl_processus and the txt_box_processus, if the results match and therefore the monitored process has the focus it switches to the keyboard selected in lst_box_clavier1, if this does not match, therefore the process does not have focus, it activates the keyboard given in lst_box_clavier2.
The final goal being to monitor a process (in my case a video game not offering to modify the keys) and to switch between qwerty and azerty depending on whether or not it has focus.
But the current logic has a problem: if I put the keyboard change outside the if condition of the timer_switch, it changes it every x time (defined interval), but if I put it in the verification condition then it only changes it when my software regains the focus. I added a label that shows the result of the condition, saying if my process has the focus or not, but for the keyboard change it is only carried out if my software has the focus, which is of no use, and I have to detect the change, otherwise it will be of no use.
Code :
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClavierSwitch
{
    public partial class Form_Main : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public string LayoutName { get; }
        public void GetLanguages()
        {
            // Gets the list of installed languages.
            foreach (InputLanguage lang in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages)
            {
                Lst_Box_Clavier1.Items.Add(lang.LayoutName);
                Lst_Box_Clavier2.Items.Add(lang.LayoutName);
            }
        }
        public void SetLang(int ind)
        {
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages[ind];
        }

        public Form_Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetLanguages();
        }

        private void timer_Donnees_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InputLanguage ClavierActif = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;

            if (ClavierActif != null)
                Lbl_Clavier_Actif.Text = ClavierActif.LayoutName;
            else
                Lbl_Clavier_Actif.Text = "Langue Clavier Actif : Il n'y a pas de langue actuelle";

            Process fgProc = ProcessUtils.getForegroundProcess();
            Lbl_Processus_Actif.Text = fgProc.ProcessName;
        }

        private void Chk_Box_Switch_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
        
        private void Bt_Demarre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (timer_Switch.Enabled)
            {
                timer_Switch.Enabled = false;
                Lbl_Etat.Text = "Inactif";
                Lbl_Etat.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                Bt_Demarre.Text = "Demarrer";
                Txt_Box_Interval.Enabled = true;
                Txt_Process.Enabled = true;
                Lst_Box_Clavier1.Enabled = true;
                Lst_Box_Clavier2.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                string numString = Txt_Box_Interval.Text;
                long number1 = 0;
                bool canConvert = long.TryParse(numString, out number1);
                if (canConvert == true)
                {
                    timer_Switch.Enabled = true;
                    timer_Switch.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(Txt_Box_Interval.Text);
                    Lbl_Etat.Text = "Actif";
                    Lbl_Etat.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    Bt_Demarre.Text = "Arreter";
                    Txt_Box_Interval.Enabled = false;
                    Txt_Process.Enabled = false;
                    Lst_Box_Clavier1.Enabled = false;
                    Lst_Box_Clavier2.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Lbl_Etat.Text = "Intervalle non valide";
                    Txt_Box_Interval.Text = "1000";
                }
            }
        }

        private void timer_Switch_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            string strProc = Txt_Process.Text;
            string strProcLbl = Lbl_Processus_Actif.Text;
            int result = String.Compare(strProc, strProcLbl);

            if (result == 1)
            {
                SetLang(Lst_Box_Clavier2.SelectedIndex);
                Lbl_Control.Text = "Controle : Non Focus";
            }
            else
            {
                SetLang(Lst_Box_Clavier1.SelectedIndex);
                Lbl_Control.Text = "Controle : Focus";
            }
        }

        private void Lst_Box_Clavier1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Lst_Box_Clavier2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
    class ProcessUtils
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
        public static Process getForegroundProcess()
        {
            uint processID = 0;
            IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow(); // Get foreground window handle
            uint threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processID); // Get PID from window handle
            Process fgProc = Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(processID)); // Get it as a C# obj.
            // NOTE: In some rare cases ProcessID will be NULL. Handle this how you want. 
            return fgProc;
        }
    }
}


In order to detect "state" changes in the .Text fields, you need to preserve "previous state" for one cycle. You need a "prevStrProc" and a "prevStrProcLbl" that get primed first time through with the current values. Subsequently, you only test your "if", only if, strProc or strProcLbl has changed (relative to the "previous" values). And when there is a "change", (re)set the "previous values". Anything else is redundant.
